# decltype requires instantiated object

Tags: c++, coding-style, c++11

I was experimenting a little with the C++11 standard and came up with this problem:

In C++11 you can use `auto` and `decltype` to automatically get return type for a function as, for example the `begin()` and `end()` functions below:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Container {
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
public:
    auto begin() -> decltype(v.begin()) { return v.begin(); };
    auto end() -> decltype(v.end()) { return v.end(); };
};
```

My problem here is that I have to declare the private `vector<T> v` *before* the public declarations which is against my coding style. I would like to declare all my private members *after* my public members. You have to declare the vector before the function declaration because the expression in `decltype` is a call to vector member function `begin()` and requires an instance of the object.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I would like to add that I know how to do it without `auto`, but the question is regarding the use of `auto` and `decltype`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could avoid using `decltype` at all and just set the return type to `std::vector<T>::iterator`.

If you want to use auto though you can use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to get a value from just the type like so:

```
auto begin() -> decltype(std::declval<std::vector<T>>().begin()) { return v.begin(); };
```

Comment: the power of the decltype approach is that it has the correct `this` type. including for const memberfunctions.

Comment: What Johannes says. This will fail for const member functions if you aren't careful and use `std::declval<const T>()` in those.